# Proving that the triple integral can be evaluated by iterated integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am currently in a Calculus III class and we're learning triple integrals. While learning double integrals, I was introduced to Fubini's Theorem, stating the double integral is equal to the iterated integral with respect to $x$ and $y$.

That proof is quite complicated and wasn't covered in my class, but I would love to understand it more once I've taken other more advanced maths. Anyway, the textbook gives a similar manner for evaluating triple integrals by using iterated integrals with respect to $z, y$, and $x$.

Is the proof for this triple integration essentially an expanded version of Fubini's Theorem, or is it another proof altogether? Thank you very much!

Comment: It is essentially the same proof in 3d or in $n$-dimensions so long as the domain of integration can be easily broken into a Cartesian product of 1d sets. You can prove it by breaking off one variable at a time and using the 2d version as the base case for a proof by induction.